# I want to put a variable directly next to a string

Tags: python

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
print ("walk into your room")
length = int (input("What is the length of the left hand wall? "))
width = int (input("What is the length of front wall? "))
area = length*width
print (area,"cm² is the area of your room")
```

Then the shell looks like this:

```
walk into your room
What is the length of the left hand wall? 78
What is the length of front wall? 23
1794 cm² is the area of your room
```

but i want it to say:

```
walk into your room
What is the length of the left hand wall? 78
What is the length of front wall? 23
1794cm² is the area of your room
```

so that there is no space between "1794" and "cm²"

Comment: Is your `#` key broken?

Comment: just use print("%fcm2 is the area of your room"%area)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html is a good reference

Answer (score 2):

Use string formatting:

```
print("{}cm² is the area of your room".format(area))
```

You can also use string concatenation, but formatting is preferred most of the time:

```
print(str(area) + "cm² is the area of your room")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That has really helped and it know works

Answer (score 0):

Python 3's `print()` function has an argument called `sep`, designed specifically for that:

```
print(str(area),"cm² is the area of your room",sep="")
```

By default, `sep` is set to `" "`, such that a space appears in between each two elements you want to print. If you want to use the `print()` function in Python 2.x, you can do this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

# your code

print(str(area),"cm² is the area of your room",sep="")
```

Of course, you may want to form a single string first, and then print it:

```
print(str(area)+"cm² is the area of your room")
```

---

Related documentation:

- [Python Built-in Functions - print()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#print)